# Latex document with specific page size

Tags: latex

I would like to have a latex document where the page size is 21cm x 21cm, with a 0.8cm margin.  Am using texmaker, which does not have any defined or user-defined templates for starting a basic document.  Have also checked texstudio but although it has templates, they do not conform to the 21cm x 21cm page size, those predefined are too large for what I am doing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Non-programming related questions about LaTeX are generally better suited for [LaTeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). In fact, this question already has a duplicate there: [LaTeX - how do I force PDF page height/width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31973/242828)

Comment: Was not aware.  Thank you so very much @Brian

Comment: TeXstudio has options to set the page size for a new document under  Wizards / Quick Start / Geometry